# fopen() fails sporadically

Tags: php, fopen

I know fopen() failures have been discussed profusely here, but it seems my problem has a unique twist to it: fopen() fails maybe *one out of four* times, the other times it works perfectly. I get the following error:

```
Warning: fopen(http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=0005.HK&f=nl1c1p2v&e=.csv)
[function.fopen]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in [...] on line 4
```

The fact that it doesn't happen systematically rules out most problem sources on the host server side, could it be due to the server from which I'm fopening, Yahoo Finance?

Comment: use curl. It'll return better diagnostics than fopen - getting "false" is utterly useless for figuring out the problem: "ooh, look, an error occured!"

Comment: Agreed with @Marc B.  When you use `curl_exec()` and detect an error you can call `curl_errno()` and it will return you a more detailed error reason http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html   To see the human string call `curl_error()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use curl lib instead. http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

```
function get_cURL($p_url)
{


    $ch = curl_init($p_url);

    $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3";
    $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,text/csv,application/xhtml+xml,"; 
    $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"; 
    $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0"; 
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive"; 
    $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300"; 



    // set URL and other appropriate options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    // grab URL and pass it to the browser
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $p_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);





    $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
    $this->info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $this->error = curl_error($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

return $buffer;
}
```